# How to extract part of a file name with find and awk

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, find

I have this dir structure

```
sample1__app
sample2__test
```

I want to extract `sample1` and `sample2` and then do further operation but I am stuck on this

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec awk -d'__' '{print $0}' {}  \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `awk` command is trying to *open* the files (directories in this case) and process their *content,* something `awk` is not keen on doing.

And, in any case, `$0` in `awk` is the *entire* input line - I suspect you wanted the first field, which would be `$1`.

What you really want is to process the directory names themselves (rather than their content), which you can do with something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | awk -F'__' '{ sub ("^./", "", $1); print $1 }'
```

You simply pipe the output of the `find` through `awk` rather than giving it the directory names as input files. The `sub` will strip off the leading `./` from the output, after which you simply print out the field.

---

As an aside, you may want to watch out for strange edge cases like directory names with newlines in them. I've tailored this answer to your *specific* data and it should work with simpler edge cases (such as file names with spaces in them) but newlines will cause problems.

My personal viewpoint is that people who construct file names with newlines, backspaces and such are evil, and deserve everything they get :-)

However, if you *really* need to handle embedded newlines, you can do that by not having those filenames split in the `find`-to-`awk` pipeline. To do this, create a script which handles one argument properly by using quotes (e.g., `proc.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bit="$1"             # Get the argument.
bit="${bit#\./}"     # Remove ./ at start.
bit="${bit%__*}"     # Remove from last __ onward (use %% for first).
echo "[$1] [${bit}]" # Show effect.
```

Then call that from within the `find` itself (again, quoting to ensure the argument isn't split):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec ./proc.sh "{}" ';'
```

Running that is a directory with the sub-directories (`XX` is the embedded newline):

```
dodgy__extXXwith-newline/
sample1__app/
sample2__test/
```

will handle it correctly (note the multi-line `[...]` for the "dodgy" file, and output has been slightly reformatted for readability):

```
[./sample2__test]       [sample2]
[./sample1__app]        [sample1]
[./dodgy__ext
with-newline]           [dodgy]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. is it possible that after the end i can use -exec and then another command but i want to several openation taking extracted name like -exec  mv {}.tar.gz /tmp  etc

Comment: @Mr.Mirror, your best bet is to create a shell script which receives `"{}"` as an argument, and acts on it as `"$1"` - that way you can do whatever you want in the script without having to battle against the oft-angst-inducing `find` syntax :-) As a useful side-effect, this can also get around the newline issue bought up in the answer.

Comment: Actually i wanted quick and dirty was for something to move. i wont re use it agagin so was thinking of one liner for that

Comment: I would add spaces in filenames to the evil list as well.

Comment: how can i add second exec statement after that example simple mv {}_tar b/